# Question about Socket Streams on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, stream

I want to send a UIImage to a server with socket. I'm using this code from ADC:

```
- (IBAction)searchForSite:(id)sender

{

    NSString *urlStr = [sender stringValue];

    if (![urlStr isEqualToString:@""]) {

        [searchField setEnabled:NO];

        NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

        if (!website) {

            NSLog(@"%@ is not a valid URL");

            return;

        }

        NSHost *host = [NSHost hostWithName:[website host]];

        // oStream is instance variable

        [NSStream getStreamsToHost:host port:80 inputStream:nil
            outputStream:&oStream];

        [oStream retain];

        [oStream setDelegate:self];

        [oStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]

            forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

        [oStream open];

    }

}
```

First question: I want to create an NSOutputStream object, but I find that it can only be initilized with a file, a buffer, or memory. How can I output the stream to a socket then?

Second question: The ADC's reference tells us that the method getStreamsToHost:port:inputStream:outputStream: returns the object representing an output stream to the remote host. How can the host return the output stream to itself? And where can I add output stream in the code to send to the host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First question**:

You **are** already initializing it with a *socket*. NSStream's getStreamsToHost message already gives you a socket to talk to specified host, post. Whenever you want to write to the socket, just use **oStream**.

**Second question**:

Kind of answered in the first question. Keep in mind that you are opening a socket to port **80**. So, probably you are running a WebServer on the remote host. And to be able to send an image to the remote server, you would need to implement **HTTP** protocol. Check my suggestion below. I think it will make your life easier.

---

A little suggestion:

I know you didn't ask this, but let me give you a suggestion. You are trying to send an image through a socket. I would use a higher level protocol such as **HTTP** or **FTP** to do that. Using a plain socket will force you to implement a new protocol yourself, not to mention the server side code to process incoming images.

So, if you use **HTTP**, just write a little server side script in your favorite WEB developing platform (.NET, PHP, Java, Python, RoR, CGI, whatever) and just use guidelines on [this](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/) WebPage to submit the image on iPhone. It's way easier.

Comment: When can I add UIImage data to the oStream? After [oStream open] or before 'getStreamToHost'?

Comment: It's to be after. But remember, if you are sending it to the 80 port, you are probably sending it to a Web Server. So you will have to implement HTTP protocol yourself. Please read carefully my answer. You'll be able to transmit your image if you follow my suggestions.

Comment: For my own app, port 1100 is used. And it shares the same server with a window mobile app. So I won't be allowed to change the protocol. Thanks for your answer and suggestion anyway.

Comment: If you are using port 1100 for your application, you should change this part of your code to reflect it: [NSStream getStreamsToHost:host port:80 inputStream:nil
            outputStream:&oStream];

Comment: This does not work on iOS.  NSHost is only for the Mac.